# Kotlin variable destructuring is run time or compile time

Tags: kotlin-native

Was trying to do this: `val (considerSeparation,considerNewLine) = items` and I get the error class must have fun component1() and component2() showing that the destructuring structure of kotlin native is run time not compile-time while being nice looks limiting and extra code complexity just to destruct a variable for syntax benefits i.e

```
class Items(val considerSeparation : Boolean, val considerNewLine : Boolean)

val ( considerSeparation ,considerNewLIne ) = items
```

should be compiled to:

```
class Items(val considerSeparation : Boolean, val considerNewLine : Boolean)

val considerSeparation = items.considerSeparation
val considerNewLine = items.considerNewLine
```

```
class Items(val considerSeparation : Boolean, val considerNewLine : Boolean){
   operator fun component1(): Boolean  = considerSeparation
   operator fun component2(): Boolean = considerNewLine

}
val items = Items(false,false)

val (considerSeparation,considerSeparation ) = items
```

This is because destructuring is supposed to be a syntax benefit. and right now looks like it's a syntax benefit with baggage??

Comment: Hahaha thanks... you got the gist though... changed most of i...

Comment: Hello, have you seen [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) document?  If I understood the problem correctly, this should work as you wish for data classes.

Comment: The question goes is destructuring just meant for data classes?
Else this is not convenient for all the times you might want to destructure. 
Right now the convenience of a syntax feature is left on to extra work to fit a languages design feature